# after() showing parsed html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added code to add an asterik after a text (with css classes in it). When the code runs it displays the code instead of the html being processed. 
Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("billing_state_field").getElementsByTagName('label')[0].after("<abbr class='required' title='required'>*</abbr>"));
});
```

Output:

```
<label for="billing_state" class="">STATE / COUNTY / PROVINCE / EMIRATE</label>
&lt;abbr class='required' title='required'&gt;*&lt;/abbr&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, why not use it to the fullest ?

Instead of using

`condocument.getElementById("billing_state_field").getElementsByTagName('label')[0]`

Use `$("#billing_state_field label",condocument).eq(0)`

As requested in the comments, I changed `.after( ... )` to `.html( .html() + ... )`

```js
$("#billing_state_field label").eq(0).html($("#billing_state_field label").eq(0).html() + "<abbr class='required' title='required'>*</abbr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="billing_state_field">
  <label>Test </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it displays the `*` after label. I want to show it inside label after the text. So I changed `after()` to  append()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your solution. It doesnt give any error but does nothing.

Comment: @FahadUddin As you can clearly see in the snippet, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`after` function does not take an `HTML string` but a `DOM element` or a raw text.

So your call to  `after` should look like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var abbr = document.createElement("abbr");
  abbr.setAttribute("class", "required");
  abbr.setAttribute("title", "required");
  abbr.innerText = "*";

  document.getElementById("billing_state_field").getElementsByTagName('label')[0].after(abbr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="billing_state_field">
  <label for="billing_state" class="">STATE / COUNTY / PROVINCE / EMIRATE</label>
</div>
```

Here is the documentation of `after` function on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do that:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#billing_state_field').find('label:eq(0)').after("<abbr class='required' title='required'>*</abbr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='billing_state_field'>
<label for="billing_state" class="">STATE / COUNTY / PROVINCE / EMIRATE</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you want append the `<abbr>` tag in the `<label>` tag.

There are two ways jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript.

To show the both ways jQuery and javaScript I am using two different div.

1) **#billing_state_field_1** // jQuery

2) **#billing_state_field_2** // javaScript

```js
// jQuery
$('#billing_state_field_1 label').append("<abbr class='required' title='required'>*</abbr>");


// javaScript
var billing_state_lbl = document.querySelector('#billing_state_field_2 label');
    node = document.createElement('abbr'); // Create element node
    textNode = document.createTextNode('*'); // Create text node
node.classList = "required"; // Add class
node.appendChild(textNode); // Add text node to element node 
node.setAttribute('title','required'); // add attribute on element node 
billing_state_lbl.appendChild(node); // Append newly created element node
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Handle by jQuery -->
<div id="billing_state_field_1">
    <label for="billing_state">STATE / COUNTY / PROVINCE / EMIRATE - 1 </label>
</div>

<br>

<!-- Handle by javaScript -->
<div id="billing_state_field_2">
    <label for="billing_state">STATE / COUNTY / PROVINCE / EMIRATE - 2 </label>
</div>
```